# Quero pesquisar se um login existe em um dicionário em python

Tags: python, dicionário

Tô fazendo um programa simples em python utilizando dicionários e listas como cadastro de um login para clientes, queria implementar uma condição de não permitir a criação de dois clientes com o mesmo login. Se o cliente escolher um login já existente, mostrar uma mensagem de erro, não realizar o cadastro e retornar ao menu principal.

```
clientes = []


def CadastrarCliente():
    dados['nome'] = str(input("Nome completo: "))
    dados['login'] = input("Login: ")
    dados['senha'] = input("Senha: ")
    dados['email'] = input("E-mail: ")
    dados['nascimento'] = input("Data de nascimento:")
    dados['telefone'] = int(input("Telefone: "))
    clientes.append(dados)

while True:
    print('[1] Cadastrar cliente')
    print('[0] Sair')

    opcao = int(input('Opção: '))

    if(opcao == 0):
        break

    elif(opcao == 1):
        dados = {}
        CadastrarCliente()
    else:
        print("Opção incorreta")
```

Answer (score -2):

Alanis, você pode utilizar o metodo .get do Dictionary para pegar apenas o valor especifico de uma chave. Com esse mesmo método você pode criar uma lista com todos os Logins de sua lista e verificar se o novo login já existe ou não.

Você consegue ver melhor no exemplo abaixo:

```
clientes = []


def CadastrarCliente():
    dados = {
        'nome': str(input("Nome completo: ")),
        'login': input("Login: "),
        'senha': input("Senha: "),
        'email': input("E-mail: "),
        'nascimento': input("Data de nascimento: "),
        'telefone': int(input("Telefone: "))
    }

    login = dados.get('login')
    list_login = [cliente.get('login') for cliente in clientes]

    if login in list_login:
        return False
    else:
        clientes.append(dados)
        return True


while True:
    print('[1] Cadastrar cliente')
    print('[0] Sair')

    opcao = int(input('Opção: '))

    if opcao == 0:
        break

    elif opcao == 1:
        cadastro = CadastrarCliente()
        if cadastro is True:
            print("Cliente Cadastrado com sucesso!!")
        else:
            print("Cliente já cadastrado!!")
    else:
        print("Opção incorreta")
```